# Convergence of $\int _a^{\infty }t^ne^{-at}dt$

Tags: calculus, integration

I need to determine convergence of  $\int_a^\infty t^ne^{-at} \, dt$ where $n$ is a natural number and $a>0$

Since  $\int_a^\infty t^{-2} \, dt$ is convergent and $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{t^ne^{-at}}{\frac{1}{t^2}}=0$

can I conclude that it is also convergent?

Comment: $\int^\infty_a t^2\,dt$ is not convergent. I think you meant $\int^\infty_a t^{-2}\,dt $ for $a>0$. Also,  I think the $ax$ in the exponential should be $at$.

Comment: @OliverDiaz yes sorry for typo. I edited

Comment: If you meant to write $at$ instead of $ax$, then the convergence is simple for $t^n\leq e^{at/2}$ for $t$ large enough. You integrand happens to be the *tail* of the integral that defines the Gamma function at $n+1$  (a factor times the tail of the Gamma  function rather).

Comment: Isn’t this just the shifted [generalized factorial function](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Gamma/02/)?  This also goes by the name of the Π(x) function.

Comment: @OliverDiaz how did you conclude convergence by $t^n \leq e^{at/2}$?

Comment: @TymaGaidash yeah it seems so I try learn about this topic. Thanks!

Comment: Becathe then, for all large enough $t$, $t^ne^{-at}\leq e^{ta/2}e^{-ta}=e^{-ta/2}$ and $t\mapsto e^{-ta/2}$ is integrable.

Comment: @Mrnobody. In that case, the integral representation for [x!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/i4paew9o3k) diverges for any negative integer x and at x=$\infty$, I am not too sure about complex values and beyond though.

Comment: @OliverDiaz I get it now. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @TymaGaidash Thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: @TymaGaidash This is not a gamma function as the lower limit of integration is not zero. This is an example of the upper incomplete gamma function.

Comment: @AaronHendrickson I agree, then your function can be used instead.

Comment: When integrating a nonnegative function, and $a>0,$ $\displaystyle\int_a^\infty$ converges if $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty$ converges. And that integral is well known.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align}\int_a^\infty t^ne^{-at}\,dt\stackrel{u=at}
=&\int_{a^2}^\infty(u/a)^ne^{-u}\,du \\
=&a^{-n}\int_{a^2}^\infty u^ne^{-u}\,du\\
\le& a^{-n}\int_0^\infty u^ne^{-u}\,du \\
=&a^{-n}\Gamma(n+1)\equiv\frac{\Gamma(n+1)}{a^n}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1):

Is this rigorous enough?

$$\int_0^\infty t^n e^{-a t} d t= (- \partial/\partial_a)^n \int_0^\infty e^{-a t} dt
\\
=(-\partial/\partial_a)^n (1/a)$$.

This clearly yields a finite number for $a>0$ and $n$ a natural number. Your actual integral differs from this only over a finite region on which the integrand doesn't diverge, so it should yield a finite number as well.

Comment: Certainly not rigorous.

Comment: The solution posed here make this more difficult: one has to show that the derivative and the integral commute!

Comment: I don't know how to justify differentiation